# Unable to daemonise python script using systemd - No module named 'oandapyV20'

Tags: systemd, python

I'm trying to daemonise a python script using systemd, but constantly get the error "No module named 'oandapyV20'" after activating the daemon.

The script is at location:
/home/user/workingdir/script.py

The virtual environment is at:
/home/user/venv/bin/

My best guess at how to build the service from docs I've found is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=DataLoader
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/workingdir
ExecStart=/home/user/venv/bin/python3 script.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**What does work...**

python3 script.py

or activating virutal environment

source /home/user/venv/bin/activate;
python3 script.py

Although that works outside of the service, nothing I've tried works when calling from systemd.

Where am I going wrong? What am I not realising?

**Eventual solution (with little understanding)**

```
[Unit]
Description=DataLoader
[Service]
User={user_name}
Group={user_name}
WorkingDirectory=/home/{user_name}/workingdir
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 script.py
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What happens if you become root with `sudo su -` (with hyphen) and execute `cd /home/user/workingdir; /home/user/venv/bin/python3 script.py`? Is it different with `sudo su` (no hyphen)? If so, I'd scrutinize differences in environment variables. You might also run `source /home/user/venv/bin/activate; which python3` to make sure you're actually calling `/home/user/venv/bin/python3` as you currently believe.

Comment: @gnubeard thanks for your comment. After logging in as route cd /home/user/workingdir; /home/user/venv/bin/python3 script.py fails with the same module not recognised error. I installed the module whilst logged in as root, but it still fails with same error. I'm missing some fundamental concept about linux or python, why would the module not be available when root? What should I read up on? I'll work on the rest of your suggestions next.

Comment: That indicates that there's something different between your environment and root's environment. Use the `env` command to print all environment variables, and use `source /home/user/venv/bin/activate; which python3` to ensure the `python3` you're calling is the `python3` you think you're calling. If it's calling a different `python3`, I'd especially inspect differences in [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Comment: @gnubeard /home/user/venv/bin/activate; which python3 outputs /usr/bin/python3, don't yet understand why it's not using the virtual evironment.

Comment: That means that when you call `source /home/user/venv/bin/activate`, it's not setting your `$PATH` or (`$PYTHONPATH`) (at least not to what you had thought.) Hopefully that goes a long way toward explaining the discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks @gnubeard - I appear to have gotten this working now, more out of chance than an inspired solution. I've updated my question with what is now working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106238/discussion-between-gnubeard-and-goose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have been operating under the assumption that whenever you called `source /home/user/venv/activate`, the `python3` command (and the `pip3` command) would subsequently call the relevant executable from `/home/user/venv/bin`.

However, the clarification you added in the comments indicates that assumption was incorrect. You hadn't been calling the python from your virtual environment when running `script.py`; you had been calling the python in `/usr/bin` (and its corresponding `pip` too, it seems, since the python in your virtualenv doesn't seem to have the `oandapyV20` module installed, while the system python does.)

Examine the output of

```
echo $PATH
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

The `$PATH` environment variable is a colon-separated list of paths on your system to be searched when you enter a command. Either `/home/user/venv/bin` is not present in that list or it occurs after an occurrence of `/usr/bin`, which contains a match for `python3` (`$PATH` will stop being scanned after the first match.) `$PATH` is usually set by `$HOME/.bashrc` (or `/etc/bashrc` if not set there) and if your assumption had been correct, `/home/user/venv/activate` would have been setting `$PATH` to prepend `/home/user/venv/bin` to it.

`$PYTHONPATH` should tell python where to look for modules to load. ([It can also be modified or read from your script with `sys.path`.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html))

That explains why changing your systemd unit's command worked-- it's finally calling the same python that your working command did.

Comment: Thanks gnubeard, I really appreciated the help. This one's taken some time to get to the bottom of. I'm really keen on understanding linux more, but can't really see where to start. Pls feel free to recommend any good resources that helped you learn it.